# describing a span of a set of vectors geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How would you describe $\vec{x}=a\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
-2 \\\end{bmatrix}     +b\begin{bmatrix}
2  \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix} +c\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, a, b, c \in \Bbb{R} $ geometrically? This is a span of the vectors, but im not sure if the set is linearly dependent, because right now $\vec{x}$ doesn't resemble anything to me geometrically

Comment: 3 vectors in a two-dimensional vector space, so they must be linearly dependent.

Comment: what is $\frac{-1}{5}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix} + \frac{3}{5}\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: if $a=-1, b = 3, c =5$ then $\bf x = 0$  what does that say about independence?  More fundamentally, can you have 3 independent vectors in $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1):

Extend a line from $(1,-2)$ which passes through the origin. You've now identified $a(1,-2)$.

Now, from points on that line, extend lines in the direction $(2,1)$. You can also draw new lines parallel to the $(1,-2)$ line, giving yourself a grid.

What does the grid cover, even before adding the third vector? What does this say about linear dependence?